# Using our own images in a puzzle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, upload

This morning, I've tried making a puzzle in jQuery, and I'm pretty close to done, and I want to allow people to use their own images, but I can't figure out how to do it in jQuery, can it even be done in jQuery?

[here's a link to the website if needed](http://googledrive.com/host/0ByBwY60ZsbQpfm01MzBKOHRqWDJhbGxVTjdSRHF0ZE9MYWFsdTg2REVkR3BSNlkzS3BuQkk)

Answer (score 0):

Nice work. The easiest way to let users play with their own photos would be to ask for a link and then just replace the `src` attribute of your `#puzzleContainer img` element. Otherwise you'd have to upload the file using a file upload jquery plugin. [This](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) seems mighty popular.

Comment: damn, I haven't though about using links, I feel so dumb now.   as for the plugin, can I use it with google drive?

Comment: Yeah I think anything that has an API should be easy to use, including Google Drive. Have a look at https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads

Comment: I've looked at the documentation for both the library and the API and I'm lost, the library talk about json, which I've never use and it has a bunch of different libraries so I don't know which ones I'm supposed to get, as for the api, I don't know where I'm supposed to pu the code, am I supposed to put it in the script tags?